# Loading Custom Model with Tensorflow 2.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, save

I have made my own class subclassing `tf.keras.Model` and am trying to save and load a trained instance of it. I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_the_entire_model) tutorial but every time I go to load the saved model I get the same error message: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reduction'`. I've tried adding that keyword argument to my class but it changes nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem for *Tensorflow 1.14* and solved it by adding `compile=False` to the load function:

```py
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model', compile=False)
```

Even with `compile=False` it is possible to run the `model.predict()` function.

The solution originates from [this Tensorflow issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31850#issuecomment-578566637).